# clarification on how send data to previous Activity using startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I am currently trying to send data from a child activity back to its parent activity. I have used the `startActivityForResult()` to go to my child activity. However I cannot understand what I would do to put the data I want to put back to my intent and make my parent activity receive it. I have been looking at different examples online but I think it is only throwing the result variable.

As per my understanding this is what I used when I return my child activity back to the parent activity:

```
         String somestring = "somevalue";
         Intent i = getIntent();

         setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
         finish();
```

I want to load the content of the string somestring for it to return back to the parent activity. 
How can I load it back to my parent activity?

```
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

And lastly how can I capture the data in my parent activity in the `onActivityResult`?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your data to an intent, just as you would in any other situation:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.putExtra("ComingFrom", "Hello");
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Then retrieve it in `onActivityResult` in your other activity.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
{
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     String extraData=data.getStringExtra("ComingFrom"));
}
```